# Check the health of MySql database using spring integration and spring boot actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

What is the best way to to create a rest api endpoint which checks the health for different application resources, like database, Amazon SQS etc in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring-boot-actuator` provides health for datasource.

Use `/health` API after adding actuator.

Here is the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators) for the available health indicators and how to create a custom health indicator. Here is the [documentation on security details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions) to show full content of health indicators.

Comment: This is just for datasource health check... I am looking for something that fits best for checking many resources' health

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Spring Boot actuator provides many health checks, at least for all technologies it integrates with (Mongo, Elastic, Mail, RabbitMQ to name a few). If your technology isn't on the list, add a custom HealthIndictator` don't try to roll your own, use and extend what the framework provides.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need nothing more unless custom [`HealthIndicator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_writing_custom_healthindicators):

```
@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks good, and seen that on while searching on google. I thought there should be some better approach

Comment: Not sure in your concern. See Martin's comment above. He is pointing to you the same approach